# I have both SharePoint Designer 2010 & 2013, When I click Edit Library on SharePoint 2010 Site

Tags: designer

I have a problem when I click on "Edit Library" to open SharePoint designer. I think it is because I have both 2010 & 2013 installed on my PC.

Is there a way for me to make 2010 default so that whenever I click on Edit Library, it opens 2010 sharepoint and not give any errors?!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I have not found a way to have 2 versions of Designer on one computer and have them behave properly.  My solution was to put one on a Dev VM for when I needed the less frequently used version.

Comment: I see... I am struggling so hard, I need to get on designer 2010 to edit the workflows but this is preventing me from doing it!!

Comment: @Masarubae I've also had luck with opening designer 2010 and then entering the site address instead of clicking the "edit in Designer" button.

Comment: yeah.. I've tried that several times and it gives me an error saying 'this is non-sharepoint site' when this is 100% the sharepoint site that our company uses....

Comment: @Masarubae Ensure you are using the correct URL portion.  http:\\site.company.com\sites\base  Make sure not to direct it to a library/list or an .aspx page.

Comment: I don't intend to have a discussion in comments, but it seemed pertenant to mention that if you have MS Office of a different version, adding Designer will break some things in IE.  You will need to run an Office repair after installing.